# How to calculate $P(X>a|X>a+b)$ and relate the meaning of a conditional equation to a real life situation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

[image]

[image]

---

What I did:

I found the Cumulative distribution, which is:

$$P(X\leq x)=1-e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$$

Then

I know that :

> $$P(X>a+b|X>a) \cdot P(X>b) = P(X>a|X>a+b) \cdot P(X>a+b)$$

So we have to find $P(X>a+b|X>a)$ , so therefore I re-arranged:

$$P(X>a+b|X>a) = \frac{P(X>a|X>a+b) \cdot P(X>a+b)}{P(X>b)}$$

So I found whatever I know to find :

$P(X>a+b)=e^{\frac{-(a+b)}{\theta}}$

$P(X>b)=e^{\frac{-b}{\theta}}$

But I dont know  how to find :

$$P(X>a|X>a+b)$$

Please help me how to calculate the value.

---

*Also, Assumming this Identity. I tried to think about the next part, I don't know the meaning of this equation when X is the number of days. Please shed some light.*

I know that

$P(X>a|X>a+b)=P(X>b)$

Kindoff Means:

The probability of the number of days " X" is greater than b is the same as the probability of the number of days being greater than a+b , given that the number of days is greater than b.

How do I write this in a meaningful way concerning treatment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have calculated the cmf you are almost done, since $$P(X>a+b|X>b)=\frac{P(X>a+b \text{ and }  X>b)}{P(X>b)}=\frac{P(X>a+b)}{P(X>b)}=\frac{e^{\frac{-a+b}{\theta}}}{e^{\frac{-b}{\theta}}}=e^{\frac{-a}{\theta}}$$

The meaning of the equation is the memoryless property of the exponential distribution. Whether you are at day say $0$ or at day $b$ then the probability that patient needs $a$ more days of treatment is the same.

Comment: Im sorry :/ Im trying my best to understand.  But what you have found won't prove the result :/ and how come $P(A|B)=P(A\cup B)$? As for the meaning Im still trying to think about what your trying to say.

Comment: @TheArtist It's $\mathsf P(A\mid B) = \frac{\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(B)}$ because $A\cap B=A \iff A\subset B$

Comment: Ok Thanks :) :)

Comment: Oh got it :D thanks @GrahamKemp